# Clangd doesn't recognize raylib.h as a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, intellisense, raylib

made the switch to clang to continue on a game project I'm making but got into intellisense issues as clang can't recognize packages installed on my C:/ drive such as raylib, I've tried measures to add paths in the includePath option in c_cpp_properties.json but the problem still persists

my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/raylib/raylib/src/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33",
                "PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33",
                "PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
            ],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33",
                "PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: ***Exactly*** where are the Raylib header files located?

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is for intellisense only. It's has nothing to do with building. What exactly is your problem as ***clang can't recognize packages installed*** is not a good problem description.

Comment: @drescherjm Sorry for not giving a good enough description, my problem doesn't lie in the building since it runs normally, I'm just confused on why clangd's intellisense gives me errors saying that the raylib.h file doesn't exist when I specified in the json file where to look.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in C:\raylib\raylib\src

Comment: That's the location of `raylib.h`? It's `C:\raylib\raylib\src\raylib.h`? (Which I *assume* is the missing file, though it's impossible to say since you don't give us any details)